# Pass values from popup to parent page with 3 components Angular

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

What I'm trying to achieve is:- to pass value from **Number 3 (warehouse Component) when I select row which is works fine** and it's the code used to selection

```js
  onSelect(ev) {
    this.wearHouseId = ev.selected[0].wearHouseID; //i want to send this selected value to "number 1 component spareparts"
    this.wearHouseName = ev.selected[0].wearHouseName;
    console.log(this.wearHouseId)
    console.log(this.wearHouseName)
  }
```

to
**Number 1 (spareparts Component)** when I click on
**Number 2 (modalPopup Component) Button**
using Angular & ngx-datatable

[image: Number 1: spareparts, Number 2: modalPopup Component, 3:warehouse Component]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example, lets call `spareparts` component the parent, `modalPopup` component the child, and `warehouse` component the grandchild. You wish you emit a value from the grandchild to the parent.

One simple way is to create event emitters in child and grandchild components. You could then redirect the emitted value from the grandchild through child to the parent component. Try the following

**Grandchild**

warehouse.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-warehouse',
  templateUrl: './warehouse.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./warehouse.component.css']
})
export class WarehouseComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onChangeId = new EventEmitter();
  .
  .
  onSelect(ev) {
    this.emitWarehouseId(ev.selected[0].wearHouseID);  // <-- emit id here
    this.wearHouseId = ev.selected[0].wearHouseID;
    this.wearHouseName = ev.selected[0].wearHouseName;
    console.log(this.wearHouseId)
    console.log(this.wearHouseName)
  }

  private emitWarehouseId(id: any) {
    this.onChangeId.emit(id);
  }
}
```

**Child**

modal-popup.component.html

```html
<app-warehouse (onChangeId)="onChangeWarehouseId($event)"></app-warehouse>
```

modal-popup.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-popup',
  templateUrl: './modal-popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-popup.component.css']
})
export class ModalPopupComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() warehouseId = new EventEmitter();
  .
  .
  private onChangeWarehouseId(id: any) {
    this.warehouseId.emit(id);
  }
}
```

**Parent**

spareparts.component.html

```html
<app-modal-popup (warehouseId)="onChangeWarehouseId($event)"></app-modal-popup>
```

spareparts.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-spareparts',
  templateUrl: './spareparts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spareparts.component.css']
})
export class SparepartsComponent implements OnInit {
  private onChangeWarehouseId(id: any) {
    console.log(id); // <-- receive id in parent component
  }
}
```

Comment: Above all else, I might want to thank you for this exertion which I value it, second upset for late responding
at long last, your example works like charm yet there was a negligible thing is missing in my code yet after I comprehend this example well I could end it up >> thank you once more